# Wordpress usernames with special characters using wp_get_current_user() returns nothing

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation with a login system. The usernames are company names, which might include the danish characters Å,Æ,Ø.

When loggin in, these characters do not cause a problem. But when the user is logged in, and i try to get the currently logged in user, the current user_login and role is not displayed. This has worked before, and stopped working recently. I am using the following code:

```
<?php
function visbruger(){

      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        $BrugerRolle = "";
        $Rolle = implode(', ', $current_user->roles);

        if($Rolle == 'Light'){
            $BrugerRolle = "CE- mærkning";
        } 
        else if($Rolle == 'Normal-1'){
            $BrugerRolle = "FPC Light";
        }
        else if($Rolle == 'Normal-2'){
            $BrugerRolle = "FPC Normal";
        } 
        else{
         $BrugerRolle = implode(', ', $current_user->roles);  
        }

       echo 'Logget ind som: ' . $current_user->user_login . " "." | "." ";
       echo 'Abonnement: ' . $BrugerRolle . "\n";

}

add_shortcode('brugervis', 'visbruger');
?>
```

This function should return something like this:

```
Logget ind som: Company name | Abonnement: FPC Normal
```

But when using æ,ø,å in the username, it returns:

```
Logget ind som: | Abonnement:
```

Like `wp_get_current_user()` can't get users with special characters in their username. How do I fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`user_login` is sanitized with  `sanitize_user()` when inserting user. That means such special characters would be stripped out. See what characters are allowed in `user_login` after cleanup. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_user/

Rather than displaying `$current_user->user_login` in your function, you can display `$current_user->display_name` so that such special characters are displayed correctly.

Comment: I'm filtering sanitize_user() in functions.php, so that the special characters are allowed in user_login. In the database the user_login is displayed correctly with the special characters.